# Does using Edit in the Close Review queue count as a Do Not Close vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review

I've been reviewing Close-voted questions on SO. Sometimes I think if they're edited into shape they might be a real question after all. Sometimes I think yeah, that's a dupe, but it's a hot mess and it needs to be tidied up even if it is closed.

If I click the big Edit button, when I save my changes I move on to the next item in the review queue. I can't Close or Do Not Close afterwards. If I want to close, I can follow a workflow like this:

- Click Close in review and go through the steps
- Pay no attention to the next question I am shown and click History
- Find my question and click it
- Edit, comment or whatever as I see fit

I can also Edit first, then use History to find the question and vote to close as usual.

However if I don't want to close, do I need to vote Do Not Close and then go find it in the history to fix it up? Or does editing it carry an implied "Do Not Close" of its own?

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer correct; see [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-completed-or-invalidated)

Comment: the duplicate does NOT answer the question. I didn't ask whether it is removed from the queue or not. I asked if Edit implies Do Not Close. I see no information about that in the dupe. (There's a lot of info there, perhaps it's buried?)

Comment: The answer there states that review tasks are completed once they receive three Leave Open (formerly Do Not Close) reviews and Edit reviews combined - the implication being they count the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While both "Edit" and "Do Not Close" can dequeue a post from the Close Votes queue, they are not the same:

- Editing a post immediately dequeues it. It will be re-enqueued if it receives another close vote.
- The behavior of "Do Not Close" is not set in stone, but as it currently stands, once a post receives 5 "Do Not Close" reviews, it is dequeued and its close votes begin to age away.

As a side note, to see the post you just reviewed, you can use your browser's back button instead of clicking "history".

Comment: To clarify: if I Edit from the review queue, the post is less likely to end up closed than if I Do Not Close from the review queue and then find and edit the post independently? However it is not more or less likely to be closed whichever work flow I follow if I want to close it, because my independent close vote would re-queue it. Yes?

Comment: Yes. We didn't optimize for the scenario of wanting to edit AND close.