# Editing a question in review automatically skip to the next one

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

In the review tab *Close votes* if you edit a question it automatically goes away. I'm quite against this behavior. I assume that this thing has been implemented thinking that *if you edit an answer it means that you don't need to close it anymore*.

Even if this is true most of the time, it has at least one case in which this is not totally true. Let's examine each closing vote:

- **exact duplicate**: here we obviously don't need to edit it since it will be always considered as a link to another question (the original one).
- **not constructive**: here if we edit the answer we expect it to finally fit the SO format, so it's good to skip to another one.
- **not a real question**: if it's hard to tell what's being asked in that question, it's hard that an edit from an external user will give a mean to the question.
- **too localized**: it should just be closed.

And finally we have to consider the last one:

- **off topic**

It's clear that if an answer is off topic we have two options:

1. The question is just off topic an no other Stack Exchange websites can manage it
2. The question is off topic and should be moved to another Stack Exchange site

Now in the second option we could see some grammar error or mistakes and want to improve it **and then** close it as off topic to migrate it. But as it current stands it just doesn't let you do both, either one or the other.

How could we solve this problem?

We could create another review tab *migrations* in which you can edit a question and the click either on *keep it here* or *migrate*. In this tab would go only the questions that can be migrated to another Stack Exchange website.

We have to consider also that this review tab would split the way too big amount of *Close votes* questions.

Also the *migrations* tab would be (I don't have considered this seriously, but I'll let you decide) limited to people who has other accounts in the Stack Exchange networks which know better than anyone else if that question suit another site.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind you do have a back button.  It's not *impossible* to edit and close, it's just not *convenient* to do both.  Given that doing one covers the vast majority of cases, the net effect is positive to just go right to the next item.  It's still *possible* to handle the edge cases when they come up.

You could potentially request a `Back` button be added to the form, just to make it clearer to the user that it's an option.  (Whether it performs a back via the browser vs having the SO server remember the history is a decision I leave to others.)  Going beyond that just seems like way too much work for too small of a problem.

Comment: I don't have any stats for these "edge" cases, as you call them, but I've encountered something like 30+% of the question being flagged as "off topic" and considering that most of them can be migrated (only old ones can't), we are talking approximately of 15% of the questions.

Comment: @Jeffrey The majority of questions that are "offtopic" should *not* be migrated.  You don't migrate all questions asked within the past 60 days.  Questions should be migrated that are of high quality that the destination site really *wants* to have, not just anything that doesn't belong on the current site.  Any post likely to be closed or need significant edits immediately after being moved shouldn't be migrated in the first place.  Also keep in mind that as long as you don't go back more than 50% of the time it's a net win to automatically go to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I asked about this before: [Does using Edit in the Close Review queue count as a Do Not Close vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151414/does-using-edit-in-the-close-review-queue-count-as-a-do-not-close-vote)

If you want it closed, vote to close it and then go to the question (for example, using the history tab) and do your edit. If you don't want it closed, go ahead and edit and don't worry that you didn't vote Do Not Close.