# Tag and title edits should not remove a question from Close queue

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, vote-to-close

Any edit from the Close Queue [removes the question from the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162034/) — even if the editor [did nothing but add a tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/353551). This is inconsistent with the behavior of the Reopen Queue: for an edit to put a question there, it [has to modify the question body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/).

The edits that touch only the title and/or tags of a question are *unlikely* to change its closability, and therefore should not remove the question from Close Queue.

Comment: I must admit that I seldom feel the need to edit from the queue (but this on SO) and if I think it is worth it I visit the question instead.