# Does raising a flag again after a LQ answer was kicked off the queue by "Edit" actually work?

Tags: support, review, edits, flags, review-abuse

The [rationale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/162034/392799) behind allowing the *Edit* button in the LQ (low-quality) review queue is if a reviewer didn't actually fix "all the problems" (what the usage guide says), it will at least bump the post for more eyes.

My experience, and [others'](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3207) too, is that reflagging does nothing, and unless you ask a mod to check your flag, it will eventually age away. For the time being, I'm looking for support regarding this issue.

One such answer where the flag didn't (as far as I can see) create a new review queue and the Edit button was [misused](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/46508):

- <s>https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/70283/timeline</s> (Update: A moderator has now deleted the post.)

---

PS I come across this issue relatively a lot, so it is of concern; I can only imagine what more busy sites go through.

I already brought up the relevant part that concerns the Aviation site by asking, "[Please don't make a minor edit for a low-quality-flagged post from the review page](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3931)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My experience, and others too, is that reflagging does nothing

Well, if your intention is to send it to the Low Quality Posts review queue again, that certainly won't happen, according to [this answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/295232):

> Once reviewed, further flags do not re-add the post to the queue. At this point, a moderator will need to intervene. These flags will continue to appear in the moderator queue for this reason.

So it's up to ♦ moderators then. I know that on Ask Different where I moderate we regularly process VLQ and NAA flags, but some colleagues across the network basically ignore them and choose to let the community handle them via the review queues (which can make a lot of sense given the workload and/or the activity of the review queues on that site). I'm not sure if Aviation is one of those sites.

> and unless you ask a mod to check your flag, it will eventually age away

That could certainly happen; there's no indication in the flag dashboard if a pending VLQ/NAA flag is being reviewed by the community or not, and if the moderators' strategy is to leave them alone, they'll eventually age away. IIRC we would see that a previous flag against the post has been dismissed, but not that is was edited in between flags since the only pending flag was cast after the edit was made.