# Edit and Reopen locks in

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, review, vote-to-reopen

I was in the review/reopen queue on Stack Overflow and saw a post that I thought just needed some editing to be reopened.  After going into it I realized that I was wrong and hit the back button on the browser.  This took me back to the review page, but showed me as doing the `Edit and Reopen` option.

I don't think this option should complete if the Edit isn't actually done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ability to retract reopen/delete votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes)

Comment: No, it's not about retracting, it's about the vote should never have counted in the first place, because the action wasn't completed.

Comment: I can probably count on the fingers of one hand the number of times I've used the back button in the browser on an SE site.  I've gotten so used to the back button being broken in web sites that I no longer use it. I see what you're saying about the Edit and Reopen thing, but how would the software know exactly?  Does it have to dig into the edit history and find your name as the last edit?  What if you edited it on another page?  Should the original page update in real-time?  How deep does this well go?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, well, on the 'first answers' queue I can do an edit and then it brings me back to the page for me to hit the __`I'm Done`__ button, so seems like they've already figured out how to do that.

Comment: That behavior is consistent with the behavior you're describing in your question, unless you are claiming that the "I'm done" button doesn't enable unless you *actually* edit the post.

Comment: I'm not sure how you see it as consistent.  The point is that they can tell that I did an edit and enable the button (though I never didn't do the edit there to know if it actually needed that done to enable).  It seems like it would track my actions when I'm doing a review action from beginning to end, and intelligently enable/disable functionality based on my actions.

Comment: `though I never didn't do the edit there to know if it actually needed that done to enable` -- That's what I'm saying.  I suspect the trigger occurs when you choose to edit.  So you'd have to fix it there also.

Comment: Ok, I see, but don't you think we could probably code that to happen?

Comment: I don't know.  I don't set the priorities. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just remove Edit and Reopen and instead give us an Edit button. When we're done editing, we come back to the post and can then either Reopen or not. This would also help my workflow when I want to leave something closed because it's missing vital information, but I can at least clean it up.

Related: [Does using Edit in the Close Review queue count as a Do Not Close vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151414/147247)

Comment: This change would be breaking the workflow of quite a few people as well.

Comment: Breaking? You have to do another click when you are all done editing. There's no new tab needed, no hitting back, just one extra step at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone else actually managed to make this happen? I've canceled out of edits plenty of times in the past after changing my mind, and just tested this again using both the "cancel" button in the review UI, and the browser's back button to get out of the edit. In both cases, the item being reviewed remains unreviewed.

If you can reproduce this, give me a link to a review task where it happened and I'll try to figure out what happened.