# Questions that get edited in the close review queue and get another vote aren't pushed to the review queue again

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

According to [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162058/213575), a post that gets edited in the close review queue and gets another vote should be reintroduced to the review queue. Apparently this doesn't happen when:

- the person that edited the question (by mistake or misjudgment) casts their vote.
- someone else casts their vote when the question still has close votes active.

I can't verify with certainty due to the nature of the bug (I need at least 3 users with close votes and a couple of hours to test) but that's what my observations have gathered.

Comment: You could test on a smaller site, no?

Comment: @3ventic the only small sites are *too small* to provide precise data points or fast due the fair amount that needs to be closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151443/213575

Comment: Ah, yes, that is a clear enough confirmation. Damn, I'd like to see that behaviour changed. I do suppose that the edit bumps the post and the renewed attention may attract additional close votes but if those don't requeue the post either....

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, [animuson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/162034/213575) couldn't so what could a mere mortals do