# Edit and leave closed?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

One of the most common reasons for questions to end up in the reopen queue is when a closed question is edited.

Sometimes, those edits are not in good faith, like this one:

[image: edit-and-leave-closed]

I do not want to either "reopen" nor "skip" this one, and "edit and reopen" gives me the opportunity to remove the edit, but casts a reopen vote at the same time, which I do not want. What I end up doing here is to open the link to the question, perform the edit task there, and choose "leave closed" in this tab.

This could have been much easier if there was an alternative for "edit and leave closed". I am aware that there may be too many buttons then, so alternatively, the button could be just labelled "edit", and you had to choose between leave closed and reopen afterwards.

Comment: More importantly the user that did that edit can be flagged for such behavior IMO

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151414/does-using-edit-in-the-close-review-queue-count-as-a-do-not-close-vote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing is not the purpose of the review queue, although it is one of the options you have usually available, like flagging, which could be useful in this case too, or voting.

The best option you have now is to open the question by clicking on the link (if you hold Ctrl or Cmd it will open in a new tab for you). You can do the editing there and choose the appropriate action in the review queue.

In my opinion, stuffing the review queue with all options you normally would have had makes it harder to understand what the purpose is of the queue, which is a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, there are two (actually three) separate issues, each with their own solution: (1) an bad edit triggering (2) a misplaced "re-open request" with (3) a user acting in bad faith. Theoretically, this *could* be handled as one operation, but it would be UI nightmare to account for every possible combination in one atomic operation. So handling these in order: (1) click through to the question edit out the offending material, (2) flag the content to bring the user to the mod's attention, and (3) mark the queue entry as "leave closed".